# GUI Emacs opens new session of firefox with strange border

Tags: web-browser

I am using emacs27 on Elementary OS.
I had to tweak `Exec=/usr/bin/env XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 emacs27 %F` in `.desktop` file to be able to run it in GUI mode.

When I am in org mode and try to open a link in GUI Emacs,
it opens Firefox with very wide black borders around it and I am logged out of all services.

When I do the same in terminal `emacs -nw`, the link normally opens in my system firefox without strange borders and I am normally logged in to all services.

How can I make GUI Emacs open "regular" firefox instance?

Comment: perhaps you have several versions of firefox installed?

Comment: I did experiment with Flatpak version, Snap version and installing via `sudo apt`. I'll check if that is the case.